# AutoFocus for Android 4.0

Tags: android

I have an camera app done for Android 2.3 which basically starts the CameraPreview class and draws a rectangle over the preview and does autofocus within the preview. It works without any issues in Nexus S running on Android 2.3.

But when I run this app on Galaxy Nexus running on Android 4.0 the autofocus functionality is not working.  I checked the developer website and the Camera.AutoFocusCallback is still available for Android 4.0.

Any idea what's the issue?

Thanks in Advance,
Perumal

Comment: noticed the same problem in a 4.0 AVD

Answer (score 0):

Use SurfaceHolder.Callback -> surfaceCreated to know when you can start the AutoFocus. If the surfaceholder isn't created autofocus will fail.